# CName redirects to www.example.com but not to http://example.com

Tags: cname

I moved a site to WP Engine. I changed the zone file `CNAME` to point to the wpengine domain. So now I can access `www.example.com`, but I can not access `http://example.com` (takes me to GoDaddy "no site page").

What am I doing wrong? I attached a screenshot below. The `A` record points to GoDaddy's own IP. Wo Engine does not provide an IP to point to. They ask you to use a `CNAME`. I added a wildcard to the `CNAME` (`*`) to see if that would work. But no luck.

I just want to be able to access the website whether I type the `www` or not.

[image]

Comment: Change the first line from a . (dot) to an actual domain name?

Comment: I just removed the A record and it worked.

Comment: Good news! I am glad you found the answer.

Comment: @gdaniel Can you add your comment as an answer (with a little bit of elaboration if possible) and accept it so that the question will be considered resolved and won't keep reappearing in the _active_ list of questions? Thanks.